# sample js youtube api doesn't work locally

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, youtube-api

I need to use youtube api to upload videos to the user's youtube channel, I tried this sample html/js code(the full one at end page)

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/client-side-web-apps#choosing-access-scopes

which should sign-in the user with oauth2.
I put it in a simple .html file and tried to access it locally from my browser but when I click the button nothing happens

I used my api key and Id as the guide said, I put as js source: http://localhost when initializing
but clicking the button doesnt do anything

this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script>
  var GoogleAuth;
  var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl';
  function handleClientLoad() {
    // Load the API's client and auth2 modules.
    // Call the initClient function after the modules load.
    gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
  }

  function initClient() {
    // Retrieve the discovery document for version 3 of YouTube Data API.
    // In practice, your app can retrieve one or more discovery documents.
    var discoveryUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest';

    // Initialize the gapi.client object, which app uses to make API requests.
    // Get API key and client ID from API Console.
    // 'scope' field specifies space-delimited list of access scopes.
    gapi.client.init({
        'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
        'discoveryDocs': [discoveryUrl],
        'clientId': 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
        'scope': SCOPE
    }).then(function () {
      GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
      var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
      setSigninStatus();

      // Call handleAuthClick function when user clicks on
      //      "Sign In/Authorize" button.
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').click(function() {
        handleAuthClick();
      }); 
      $('#revoke-access-button').click(function() {
        revokeAccess();
      }); 
    });
  }

  function handleAuthClick() {
    if (GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
      // User is authorized and has clicked 'Sign out' button.
      GoogleAuth.signOut();
    } else {
      // User is not signed in. Start Google auth flow.
      GoogleAuth.signIn();
    }
  }

  function revokeAccess() {
    GoogleAuth.disconnect();
  }

  function setSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
    var isAuthorized = user.hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE);
    if (isAuthorized) {
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign out');
      $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
      $('#auth-status').html('You are currently signed in and have granted ' +
          'access to this app.');
    } else {
      $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign In/Authorize');
      $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'none');
      $('#auth-status').html('You have not authorized this app or you are ' +
          'signed out.');
    }
  }

  function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
    setSigninStatus();
  }
</script>

<button id="sign-in-or-out-button"
        style="margin-left: 25px">Sign In/Authorize</button>
<button id="revoke-access-button"
        style="display: none; margin-left: 25px">Revoke access</button>

<div id="auth-status" style="display: inline; padding-left: 25px"></div><hr>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" 
        onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" 
        onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
</body>
</hmtl>
```

Comment: Please provide your (relevant) code so we know what's going on. As is, it is nearly impossible to help you.

Comment: While you used the google guide, we need your actual code to try to find what is wrong. As such, add your (relevant) codes that it can be reviewed. Did you try to debug the code? Did it hit your break point?

Comment: code added above